# What is provoking a strange 'break' after 'gets.chomp' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, break

I am following [this tutorial](http://ruby.about.com/od/textadventure/ss/Making-A-Text-Adventure-Game-In-Ruby.htm) to create a text adventure but I am having trouble with the command prompt (a mere [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)): whenever I hit enter after the **gets.chomp** order that retrieves the user string, the program finishes unexpectedly returning no error.

This is the code for the console, a method for the Player class:

```
    def play
      loop do
          do_look
          print "> "
          input = gets.chomp #The program seems to BREAK here.
          puts "[DBG] input = #{input}"
          command(input)
          puts "[DBG] Command '#{input}' finished."
      end
    end
```

I used to think that it was something with the **command** method (the one that gets the first word as a verb and the rest as arguments so the player can say, f.e., *go north*); but after marking both methods with debug tags (puts "[DBG]...") I realized my program does not even print the line above **command(input)**, so I guess something goes wrong after **gets.chomp** gets the string.

Do you have any idea about what is going on?

Note: the REPL is triggered this way:

```
$gamer = player
$gamer.play
puts "Program finished"
```

Comment: If the program exits, what is the error? On what platform are you? I can easily create a small program, without `do_look` and `command` and that just works. Try commenting `command(input)` to be sure :)

Comment: I am using Ruby 1.9.3p194. The problem is that it returns no error but finishes the loop with apparently no reason and exits the program instead re-printing the '> ' prompt again. I am starting to think that it may have to do with do_look, but it is still strange because the first time that do_look is evaluated it works perfectly :(

Comment: `do_look` may change something. Keep in mind that you are running it in repl not executing ruby file(`ruby file.rb`). Sometimes particular repl(irb/pry) shows different errors. Try running it as ruby program(`ruby your_file.rb`) as it may show you errors(repl sometimes doesn't shows errors).

Comment: I am running it as a ruby program already ;) But I did not know that both ways may trigger different outputs.

Comment: Try to separate the gets and the chomp calls ; what do you enter ? Can you produce a self contained short program exhibiting the issue ?

Comment: Could you provide full code?

Comment: Yes, although somehow we solved it because: 1. I kept an 'include player.rb' in the code while I had merged both classes in a single file and 2. because **command** called a method respond_to? with a typo in the instance of player. Somehow it seemed that there were a class defined twice and a later method calling both of them, a non-existen file and the defined class. By solving both issues the problem passed away :/ (Thanks to Daniel Knoppel, who helped me to solve it).

Comment: Sooooooo it was a problem in `command`. Hard tempted to say _I told you so_ ;) Printing statements for debugging is not always reliable, because printing is to a buffer, which is not always automatically flushed. More info here: http://mattberther.com/2009/02/11/puts-vs-print-in-ruby